# Using WHERE in aliased concatenated fields gives 'unknown column' error

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause, alias

I have the following query:

```
SELECT a.*, CONCAT_WS(' ', `c`.`firstname`, `c`.`lastname`) AS `customer_fullname`
FROM `tickets` a        
LEFT JOIN `customers` `c` ON (`a`.`id_customer` = `c`.`id_customer`)
WHERE a.`id_raffle` = 1  AND `customer_fullname` LIKE '%John%'
ORDER BY a.`id_ticket` ASC LIMIT 0,50
```

And I get the error:

```
Unknown column 'customer_fullname' in 'where clause'
```

Any advice? Please note that I can't refactor the query because it's generated by a class I'm extending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to the order of execution of a SQL query.

You can't put alias name in WHERE clause because WHERE clause is executed prior to the alias naming. HAVING worked fine because HAVING is executed after alias naming is done.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use column alias name in WHERE clause.

Try this:

```
SELECT a.*, CONCAT_WS(' ', `c`.`firstname`, `c`.`lastname`) AS `customer_fullname`
FROM `tickets` a        
LEFT JOIN `customers` `c` ON (`a`.`id_customer` = `c`.`id_customer`)
WHERE a.`id_raffle` = 1  AND CONCAT_WS(' ', `c`.`firstname`, `c`.`lastname`)  LIKE '%John%'
ORDER BY a.`id_ticket` ASC 
LIMIT 0,50
```

**OR**

```
SELECT a.*, CONCAT_WS(' ', `c`.`firstname`, `c`.`lastname`) AS `customer_fullname`
FROM `tickets` a        
LEFT JOIN `customers` `c` ON (`a`.`id_customer` = `c`.`id_customer`)
WHERE a.`id_raffle` = 1  AND (`c`.`firstname` LIKE '%John%' OR `c`.`lastname` LIKE '%John%') 
ORDER BY a.`id_ticket` ASC 
LIMIT 0,50
```

Comment: As I said, I can't refactor the query. So the aliased name is what goes into the WHERE.

Luckily, after some more digging, I found that I can use HAVING, which seems to work with an alias. Thanks for answering though.

Comment: @Marc We can't put alias name in where clause. you wither have to put concat function in where clause or pur OR operator in where clause